# How does mixed mode work in SQL

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, authentication

I am currently new to managing databases hence the question. From my lecture notes, it states that

1. A user logs into the network, Windows or otherwise.
2. The user opens a nontrusted connection to SQL Server using a username and password other than those used to gain network access.  It’s called a nontrusted connection because SQL Server doesn’t trust the operating system to verify the user’s password.
3. SQL Server matches the username and password entered by the user to an entry in the sys.syslogins table.

My question is that how does the user open a nontrusted connection to SQL? I'm confused. What does it mean by SQL Server doesn’t trust the operating system to verify the user’s password.

Comment: SQL Server itself performs the authentication when a non-trusted connection is specified.  The database engine validates the supplied SQL login and password rather than the OS.

Comment: Does it mean that as long as its not authenticated with a windows account, but through a SQL login and password, would be considered a nontrusted connection?

Comment: I think it is more correct to say `SQL Authentication` rather than nontrusted connection.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trusted connection is a legacy term and really a misnomer mostly because of how developers think of apps connecting to a database rather than how a database actually handles connection requests. SQL Server doesn't actually trusts connections. It trusts a 3rd party that you designated to authenticate a user and present the appropriate token it will then use for authorization. Just so happens Windows is the only 3rd party you can tell it to trust but it doesn't have to be.

Important things to distinguish in the process are authentication and authorization. Both SQL Server and Windows can authenticate a login attempt but only SQL Server can authorize access to objects/data. They are distinct though related parts.

When you connect using integrated authN, your security token is passed to SQL Server which then does basic checks for login mapping to establish connection. If successful, it goes on to do what it needs to for authZ(e.g. database context switch, authorization, etc...). It only cares that you have a valid token from a trusted source. In this case, it's Windows (simplifying the AD, Kerberos, etc... processes behind this). It doesn't further authenticate, it trusts that Windows has done the right checks already. Note that it doesn't have to be a network or domain user. Even local users can be setup for integrated authN but that's generally not a good idea.

If you connect with SQL Server credentials, after the pre-login handshake, your credentials are then passed to SQL Server for authorization where it'll check for login, compare password hash, policies (if any), etc... Essentially, the user authentication checks that Windows would have done when you login to a host but the security scope is SQL Server only. Until this authN is done, you are not logged in. These steps occur because the connection attempt is made with un-validated credentials rather than a secure token issued by a trusted party. Once it successfully completes authN then it goes down the same code path as before for authZ.